# Search xml files for text

Tags: xml, vb.net, xml-parsing

I have a whack of XML files and need to search through them to find particular unique text that is found within a tag, and then do all the extracting therefrom. Is there a good way to do this? I know the tag name and I know the text - that's all the information I have but it could be anywhere within dozens of files.

Comment: [XmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dc0c9ekk(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Is that the best way to do it then? Just look through each file in turn using that functionality?

Comment: I downvoted because **the question does not show any research effort**, not because it was a bad one. If the `XmlDocument` class doesn't fit your needs, the please update your question to include what you've tried and why it didn't work/ fit your needs.

Comment: Your software (or any software for that matter) isn't going to be able to magically know which file the unique text is in without opening the file to have a look!  A bit of code opening each file and checking is the fastest you're going to get - certainly beats opening them all in Notepad and using Search!

Comment: "downvoted", what does that mean? My question is not a popularity contest! :p

Answer (score 0):

[LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) provides a nice way to deal with querying XML, especially in VB.NET.  You could use something like the following to find the matching files - this assumes your element is `<B>` and you are looking for the text `ABC`.

```vb
Dim path = "C:\Path\To\Your\XML"
Dim matchingFiles =
    From f In Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.xml")
    Let doc = XElement.Load(f)
    Where doc...<B>.Value = "ABC"
    Select f
```

`matchingFiles` will be an `IEnumerable(Of String)` with the file names that matched.

This takes the *.xml files in the specified directory (`EnumerateFiles`), parses them (`XElement.Load`) and finds the ones with the required element/value.  Because it's parsing the XML, it's probably not going to be that efficient.

You could also just look for string matches, but depending on how the XML is formatted, you may have to change how you search.  The following works the same as before, although it may be less flexible about the format of the XML (this assumes the element is on a single line), but it should be a lot more efficient.

```
Dim matchingFiles2 =
    From f In Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.xml")
    Where File.ReadLines(f).Any(Function(l) l.Contains("<B>ABC</B>"))
    Select f
```

But, to answer you question in the comments, yes, you need to "look through each file in turn" some how.